# Disable OSX kernel space TCP handling

Tags: iptables, tcp, wireshark, pf

I'm writing a partial reimplementation of TCP for learning purposes, using Scapy.  My TCP server.py does not get the chance to respond to SYN messages sent to it because the kernel responds to them first (OSX 10.10.5).  I have read through the `pf.conf` man page but it doesn't seem as if there is an option to create a rule that filters packets from kernel space but not user space (frustratingly, it appears that linux `iptables` does provide such an option, `QUEUE`).

I have tried the following `pf` rule, but it filters packets outright (both from the kernel and my application).  My basis for saying this is that I do not see the packet with dest port 3000 in wireshark.

pf rule:

```
block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 3000
```

nmap command used to generate SYN:

```
nmap 192.168.1.12 -p 3000
```

How can I get the kernel to pass TCP packets to user space without doing anything?

Comment: check it out: http://newosxbook.com/bonus/vol1ch16.html

Answer (score 0):

My friend:

Is the destination machine the same as the sending machine?  If so, reword the nmap to use the loopback IP address like so:

```
nmap -P0 -sT 127.0.0.1 -p 3000
```

Note the extra options.  Next, reword the pf rule and add one for egress like this:

```
pass in quick on lo0 tcp from any to any 
pass out quick on lo0 tcp from any to any
```

If that works, tighten up the pf rule like this:

```
pass in quick on lo0 tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1
pass out quick on lo0 tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1
```

If this fails to work, check the pf to see if any packets were matched to both rules.

Hope this helps.

F.